# getting error when trying to run react project

Tags: reactjs, webpack

When i try to run a react project i'm getting below error can anyone help me in fixing this issue.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEZeG.jpg)

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with eslint. The problem is that you seem to be using `require` syntax to import your dependencies, whereas you're expected to use `import` for chosen module type (ESM).

Comment: I'm using import to include the dependencies in my code. As per the error attachment above the error is coming for the node_modules folder in which require is used to add the dependencies. Any idea why we are getting error in node_modules